# having trouble passing lower_bound a fourth argument

Tags: c++, function, lower-bound

I am not sure how to pass a comparison function to the lower_bound function. When I try to pass 4 arguments, I get an error. I would greatly appreciate an example of how to pass a comparison function in the lower_bound function.

Comment: What is the error? Can you show your code?

Comment: Without seeing any code it's hard to guess your problem. According to the documentation, you need a predicate with a signature like `bool pred(const Type1 &a, const Type2 &b);` , and then you just pass that `pred` to `lower_bound` like you would pass any parameter.

Comment: candidate expects 3 arguments, 4 provided, and no matching function for call

Comment: now I get the following error " error: no matching function for call to ‘lower_bound(int*, int*, int, bool (&)(int*, int*))’"

Comment: Your predicate accepts pointers, whereas it should take references or values

Comment: error: no matching function for call to ‘lower_bound(int*, int*, int, bool (&)(int, int))’

Comment: Edit your question with the additional information, don't put it in comments. Also show your predicate function. Help us helping you.

Comment: @gollyzoom you really must include your code when asking questions like this, voting to close.

Answer (score 2):

In the overload of [`lower_bound`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound) you are using, `Compare` must meet the requirements of [`BinaryPredicate`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/BinaryPredicate).

The example you have asked for can be found [online](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cpp_standard_library/cpp_algorithm_lower_bound_v2.htm).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

bool ignore_case(char a, char b) {
   return(tolower(a) == tolower(b));
}


int main(void) {
   vector<char> v = {'A', 'b', 'C', 'd', 'E'};
   auto it = lower_bound(v.begin(), v.end(), 'C');

   cout << "First element which is greater than \'C\' is " << *it << endl;

   it = lower_bound(v.begin(), v.end(), 'C', ignore_case);

   cout << "First element which is greater than \'C\' is " << *it << endl;

   it = lower_bound(v.begin(), v.end(), 'z', ignore_case);

   cout << "All elements are less than \'z\'." << endl;

   return 0;
}
```

Demo [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0e131af3c5eba976).